# Method not found: 'System.IO.Stream Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Item.DownloadFile()'

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I believe that I am dealing with some DLL hell.

I have a reference to Microsoft.TeamFoundations.VersionControl.Client in my application and 'copy local' is set to true. The application runs as expected on my development machine.

When I deploy this application I get an exception when trying to execute Microsoft.TeamFoundations.VersionControl.Client.DownloadFile()

> Method not found: 'System.IO.Stream Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Item.DownloadFile()'.

The version that gets deployed to my bin directory is version 9.0.3. The method exists. I noticed that a previous version of this dll does live in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies
```

How come my application does not appear to be using the assembly that I referenced within my solution and ends up in bin? How can I force this to happen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application insisted on referencing these dlls from the GAC. I ended up installing VS 2010 on the development environment and referencing the Microsoft.TeamFoundation dlls from the GAC. VS 2010 installed version 10 of the Team Foundation dlls into the development GAC.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is it, when I was trying to use TFS 2008, I had to target the x86 processor instead of Any CPU in the project settings. Without doing that, I was finding wierdness when my app deployed to other peoples machines.

Also, I deploy a number of dll's with my app, maybe you've missed deploying something that VersionControl.Client.dll depends on, and it's trying to use another dll of which it's getting the wrong version. I distribute the following (not sure if they're all needed, but you could try distributing more to see if that solved it):

Microsoft.Build.Framework.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Collaboration.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.Library.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Common.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Controls.dll
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Controls.dll
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.Client.dll
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.dll
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.dll

Comment: I set the target platform on each project in my solution to x86 and copied all the Microsoft.TeamFoundations dlls into the bin directory. Why can I not just use the dll I explicitly referenced within my project? Very lame.

Comment: Did doing that change anything? Did it work? I'm pretty sure you can use the dll you referenced within your project, I'm afraid I don't know why you got the exception you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

It appears from this link [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Item.DownloadFile() is missing](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsversioncontrol/thread/fdbf37c4-5b26-45c7-b269-b2f9c1a3f028) that there are other (and presumably safer) way to do this with other methods.